# Add content are not correctly re-parented

Tags: routes, navigation

I decided to change *Add content* `node/add/%` from Navigation menu to Management menu.

My prob is :

- Add a *Content type*
- Go to *Add content*

and my new *Add content*'s child link doesn't appear. It appears without parent in Navigation menu which is use in my case as a Top menu.

I found some answers about this bug but nothing permit me to clear my question.

Thanks in advance for helps.

PS: when I edit a content type, regardless about Menu settings I put, my *Add content* child back to Navigation menu.